# System crash after Install Chrome

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, dpkg, crash

Yesterday,
I crashed my system (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) after to I was trying to install `google-chrome` with the following command: `dpkg-deb -Xv google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb /usr/lib`.

System does not starts after that. Why did this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you able to start your system in recovery mode? You can achieve this by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> during startup.

Comment: Yes, I can start  my system in recovery mode. But I don't what I should do fix the problem.
After performed install as I sad, the system did still working. Just a few minutes it stopped responding. I try restart manually by the reset button and freeze on the loading screen:
            Ubuntu 12.04...
     *starting the winbind dasaned disable; edit /etc/default/saned
     **( ck-list-sessions:1164 ): WARNING **: Failed to get list of seats: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: success

Comment: Try starting in recovery mode and removing that package which you installed. And then see if the computer starts normally.

Comment: Hey guy! I try locate in root mode those extracted files, but I can't found it. 
I try too: apt-get dist-upgrade and deselectupgrade, nothing work.

System stop the initializing with the following command line:
**(ck-list-sessions:1164):WARNING **:Failes to get list of seats: Failed to execute program.

Comment: *This comment was before than comment above*

Hey..man! In fact I don't install chrome, I just extract .deb package in /usr/lib. I think that some file can crashing some startup file. I try starting in recovery mode, but on the screen display a few options like safe graphic mode, log in as root on the terminal and others. I do log in as root and install chrome with the command: dpkg --install google-chrome**.deb , but doens't work. I'll try remove files that I extract from google-chrome***.deb package in the /usr/lib . What you think?

Comment: can you log on to TTY1?  If yes, could you post the entire output of `dmesg` to http://paste.ubuntu.com ?  Could you also post the output of `uname -r` and `lsb_release --code` in a comment?

Comment: Could explaine me please?